# Only works with the CeleryExecutor

Tags: airflow

I am new at airflow and when i click run 'ignore all dependence' on Task Instance Context Menu like this:

[Task Instance Context Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drm79.png)

It leads to 'Only works with the CeleryExecutor'

I try to Refresh the Web UI but it doesn't work.

(I use LocalExecutor and don't want to use CeleryExecutor)

Why it happened and how can i run a single task ignore all dependence on the Web UI when i use LocalExecutor

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem. Issue was following:

With LocalExecutor you cannot run single task, you could only run the whole DAG at once. [Source code](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/b3e985a3146272ecfd3ceaaa0d8567e4e9e117d4/airflow/www/views.py#L862)

DAG was already in 'success' state.

Possible solution is to change DAG status to running.

Comment: Thanks for your solution,I read the source code and  choose CeleryExecutor to solve it

Comment: I remove check in airflow which check celeryexecutor & I was able to perform ignore_all_depndecies using local executor. Is there any drawbacks of doing this, any idea why it was not enabled for LocalExecutor.

Comment: @Deva could you please share an image /link where did you find that check?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue by selecting the first task in my DAG and mark all downstream tasks as success.

I would then clear the task I would actually want to run and the scheduler would pick it up and run this task for me.